# Extend context menu of 'My builds' in VS2019 Team Explorer and retrieve selected build

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I want to add a custom tool to the context menu in Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

I already managed to add a command there, and have it invoked. But inside the called `Execute()` method of the command, how can I retrieve the information which build was selected when the command was invoked? I need the BuildUri for that build, to pass it to my external tool...

Example is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6la7saaktz1nfv/BuildLogAnalyzerVsIntegration.zip see the method `Execute` in `class OpenBuildlogAnalyzerCommand`

Comment: Could you please share a reproduce sample with us?

Comment: Sure, the code is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6la7saaktz1nfv/BuildLogAnalyzerVsIntegration.zip

Comment: I will check it.